# ResourceContextProvider doesn't work in react-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzZ1x.png)

AdminPanel.tsx

```
 <Resource
        options={{ label: 'Transactions' }}
        icon={WorkIcon}
        name={path}
        list={TransactionsList}
      />
```

TransactionsList.tsx

```
const PostList = () => (
<ResourceContextProvider value={path}>
  
  <List syncWithLocation {...props}>
   <Datagrid  >
  <FullNameUserField label="User" source="userFirstName" />
    <TextField label="Goal Type" source="savingGoalType" />
    <TextField label="Goal name" source="savingGoalName" />
   
    <TextField label="Target Amount" source="targetAmount" />
    <SavingGoalCreationDateField label="Goal creation date" source="savingGoalCreationDate" />
    <TextField label="Strategy Name" source="strategyName" />
    <SavingGoalCreationDateField label="Target Date" source="targetDate" />
    <TextField label="Status" source="savingGoalStatus" />
  </Datagrid>
  </List>
</ResourceContextProvider>)



 <Tab label="comments" path="comments">
               <PostLisst />
 </Tab>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADjCr.png)

i can't display request's result, why?

Comment: There's not enough information here to come up with an answer, show code where you're actually trying to access the context. And what is path, a lot of information is lacking.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
const PostList = () => (...
```

I don't see the props that you need to pass, try like so instead:

```
const PostList = (props) =>
```